# Dynamically created element width overflows

Tags: css, dynamic, overflow

I am giving dynamically created element a width but it overflows.
Also if i give `overflow:hidden;`, it does not show all the text i wrote or copied there.

Tried `max-width` in my code.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/gc8wto1j/11/)

Basically; how can i get text with a specific px  without overlapping ?

Here how it looks like;

[image]

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="submit" id="add" value="add" />
<div id="list"></div>
```

SOME JS (used h1 element when i append)

```
$("#add").click(function() {
var val=$("#text").val();
$("#text").val('');
var item ="<h1>"+val+'<p class="del">x</p>'+"</h1>";

$("#list").append(item);
});
```

CSS

```
#list {
  border:1px solid #333;
  width:300px;
}
#list h1 {
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #333;
  max-width:300px;
  min-width:300px;
}
#list p {
  color:red;
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  top:-35px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there will be no space between the word you are entering then obviously it will come in one line and overflow for this situation you can use a css property `word-break:break-all`

> `word-break` property breaks the word according to the space available in parent div weather there is space in word or not

```
#list h1 {
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #333;
  max-width:300px;
  min-width:300px;
  word-break:break-all;
}
```

Check this example : https://jsfiddle.net/gc8wto1j/12/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one

```
#list h1 {
    border: 1px solid #333;
    max-width: 300px;
    min-width: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    word-break: keep-all;
}
```